# How do I extend jQuery's selector engine to warn me when a selector is not found?

Tags: jquery, sizzle

Say I make a mistake when I'm trying to find an element and I make a typo, like `$('lsdkfj')`.
Instead of jQuery returning me an empty array, I'd like to return an error message in the console, like
`"The selector 'lsdkfj' cannot be found"`. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Download an un-minified version of jQuery and start placing `console.info` calls.

Comment: Use the source Luke: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L72

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
var oldInit = $.fn.init;
$.fn.init = function(selector, context, rootjQuery) {
    var result = new oldInit(selector, context, rootjQuery);
    if (result.length === 0)
        console.info("jQuery call has no elements!", arguments);
    return result;
};
```

Comment: This would actually throw an error, since the context wouldn't be correct for `makeArray()`.

Comment: @Nick: Why? The context is `this`.

Comment: Fixed.  I'm still not sure what the problem was; `this` should have been the new object since `init` is called as a ctor.

Comment: @SLaks - Make sure to test!, this will call `console.info()` every time, since the length will be `0` on the first pass :)

Comment: Nice one, this is the sort of approach I was looking for.