# How to test if selector is valid in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, anythingslider

I am using AnythingSlider jQuery plugin which dynamically reads the hash in the URL and selects an item on a page via jQuery. The problem is the end user can break the plugin if they get to http://mydomain.com/#!demos/slider.

Is there a way to test if a selector is valid instead of letting jQuery crashing (built in function or regex)? See this jsFiddle example that tries to do $('#!demos/slider') and it crashes: http://jsfiddle.net/PvY2b/

```
$('#!demos/slider') <= Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #!demo/slider
```

Comment: Can't you just catch the error yourself and display an appropriate error message to the user?

Comment: I did a try/catch but seems like a lazy hack. Is there a built in function in jQuery or sizzle to test before letting it crash? Maybe RegEx?

Comment: First time I've seen a try/catch referred to as a "lazy hack"

Comment: @TruMan1: Why's it a lazy hack? Seems this is exactly what `exceptions` are for. Why re-invent the wheel? jQuery is already testing it for you and the way it lets you know there's a problem is by throwing an exception.

Comment: You should take an if-statement over a try/catch any day.. or it is a lazy hack.

Comment: @TruMan1: That is a awfully sweeping generalization to make. There are cases where an if statement is the better choice, for example it's often better to check for the existence of a file before trying to open it, but I don't think this is one of those. jQuery should fail fast and you shouldn't reinvent the wheel by checking what jQuery is already going to check itself.

Comment: The latest version of AnythingSlider will now ignore the hash bang completely if you set the `hashTags` option to `false`. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

From: [Basic HTML data types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2)

Therefore something like this might work:

```
if (/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-_:\.]*$/.test(selector)) {
    // $('#' + selector)...
}
```

Or simply escape it:

```
selector = selector.replace(/([;&,\.\+\*\~':"\!\^#$%@\[\]\(\)=>\|])/g, '\\$1');
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier just to wrap this block into try-catch, like here:

```
try { 
  $('#!demo/pages') 
} catch(e) { 
  alert('Your selector is invalid'); 
}
```

It's not a lazy hack: it's quite a common approach when dealing with some external components that you cannot control directly.

Answer (score 0):

As found in a previous answer: [How do I extend jQuery's selector engine to warn me when a selector is not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744997/how-do-i-extend-jquerys-selector-engine-to-warn-me-when-a-selector-is-not-found)

You have to extend over jQuery init:

```
var oldInit = $.fn.init; // cache it

$.fn.init = function(selector, context, rootjQuery) {

    var result = new oldInit(selector, context, rootjQuery);

    if (result.length === 0)
        console.info("jQuery call has no elements!", arguments);
    return result;
};
```

It will still throw errors for incorrectly syntaxed selectors, but lets say you have a correct one `$('#test')`, if no #test exists, it will at least warn you. Good for development, to help with typos etc

I've done this with `.on()` and other things, it's very powerful.